# When we use wire over Imperative method

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, salesforce1-app, lwc-wire-adapter

I am little bit confused between wire and imperative method which method used at which conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to call apex controller methods from client-side controller in LWC.

Wire method is used when you require data from the client cache and you are not doing any DML in your business logic. In wire method, `@auraEnabled(cacheable=true)` is required over  the apex method. Wire method is invoked every times whenever the component is loaded.

We use imperative method, when we don't want to call the apex method at the time when the component is loaded and when we want to perform any DML operation in our business logic.

(**Note: Imperative methods return promises, go once with this concept before implementing imperative method**)